# Undefined class 'PriorityQueue'

Tags: dart

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main(){
  PriorityQueue<double> p;
}
```

This code wont check, as Dart analyser cannot find PriorityQueue in collection. I believe that PriorityQueue is in there, so is there something wrong with my analyser? It does sometimes produce false errors, do I need to reset the cache? (I've tried, but maybe I didn't do it right)

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue is not in `dart:collection`, it is in a different "collection" unit, the `package:collection` package, which you'll need to import as a dependency.

Like this

in pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:
  collection: ^1.14.13
```

Then `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';` in your code.